# How to reset the librocket library?

Tags: c++, librocket

I'm trying to reset the library but I seem I can't.

I found [this post](http://forums.librocket.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=323), but even with the explanations in there I'm not able to do it.

**Before you see my code, what I'm trying to do is change the resolution of the window in the options menu. Maybe there is a way I don't know and this is an overkill.**

This is what I'm doing (references to "renderer" take them as an OpenGL handler):

This code is in EventHandlerOptions.cpp, in the function ProcessEvent

```
     if(ResolutionChanged)
        {
            // Change the resolution
            Renderer *renderer = GameSettings::GetRenderer();
            GUIScene *gui = GameSettings::GetGUI();
            if(renderer != NULL && gui != NULL)
            {
                bool ok;
                // Shutdown old ones
                gui->Shutdown();
                renderer->Shutdown();

                // Initialize the new ones
                ok = renderer->Init(GameSettings::GetResolutionWidth(), GameSettings::GetResolutionHeight(), 16, (bool)GameSettings::GetRepresentation());
                assert(ok);

                ok = gui->Init(GameSettings::GetResolutionWidth(), GameSettings::GetResolutionHeight());
                assert(ok);
            }
        }
```

Relevant code to the GUI (I'm using the example code that comes with the library so you will see references to Shell):

```
bool GUIScene::Init(int width, int height)
{
// Generic OS initialisation, creates a window and attaches OpenGL.
if (!Shell::Initialise("."))
{
    Shell::Shutdown();
    return false;
}

//Rocket initialisation.
Rocket::Core::SetRenderInterface(new ShellRenderInterfaceOpenGL());
Rocket::Core::SetSystemInterface(new ShellSystemInterface());

Rocket::Core::Initialise();
// Initialise the Rocket Controls library.
Rocket::Controls::Initialise();

// Create the main Rocket context and set it on the shell's input layer.
context = Rocket::Core::CreateContext("main", Rocket::Core::Vector2i(width, height));
if (context == NULL)
{
    Rocket::Core::Shutdown();
    Shell::Shutdown();
    return false;
}

Rocket::Debugger::Initialise(context);
Input::SetContext(context);

Shell::LoadFonts("Data/");

// Initialise the event instancer and handlers.
EventInstancer* event_instancer = new EventInstancer();
Rocket::Core::Factory::RegisterEventListenerInstancer(event_instancer);
event_instancer->RemoveReference();


EventManager::SetContext(context);
EventManager::RegisterEventHandler("options", new EventHandlerOptions());


EventManager::LoadWindow("demo");

return true;
}

void GUIScene::Shutdown()
{
// Shutdown Rocket.
EventManager::Shutdown();
context->RemoveReference();
Rocket::Core::Shutdown();

Rocket::Core::SetSystemInterface(NULL);
Rocket::Core::SetRenderInterface(NULL);

Shell::Shutdown();
}
```

**This is crashing on EventManager.cpp (I think in the ProcessEvent function)**

The message is: "Unhandled exception in 0x773515de in Game.exe: 0xC0000005: .... location 0x2ab60ee1"

It looks like it has something to do with the event manager, but I'm shutting it down so... ?

Thanks.